# Rest API and Web Service for Spring Boot

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-boot

I have spring boot application, with jdbctemplate i can show my data with this url

```
http://localhost:8080/query
```

and the result like this

```
[{"id_data":1,"id_user":1,"time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","ecgvalue":3.3871,"inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:25.0"},{"id_data":2,"id_user":1,"time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","ecgvalue":1.56892,"inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:25.0"},{"id_data":3,"id_user":1,"time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","ecgvalue":1.60802,"inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:26.0"},{"id_data":4,"id_user":1,"time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","ecgvalue":2.09677,"inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:26.0"},{"id_data":5,"id_user":1,"time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","ecgvalue":1.99902,"inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:26.0"}]
```

I know that is json object. My question is how to make web service from that? like Rest web service 
this is my code **QueryController.java**

```
package com.ewsn.eepiscure.controller;

/**
 *
 * @author sammy
 */
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class QueryController {

    @Autowired
    protected JdbcTemplate hiveTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/query")

    public List query() {
        List data = hiveTemplate.queryForList("select * from ecg.hivetbluserdata limit 100");
        return data;
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't have a definitely answer but in Grails (which is based in Spring) you have to import `grails.converters.JSON` then make this action render a JSON, I mean, replacing `return data` for `render data as JSON`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interesting in creating "REST web services" in Java using Spring, I would recommend taking a look at Spring Data Rest module which allows for creating

> *hypermedia-driven REST web services on top of Spring Data repositories*

See http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/